# Permission Denied when using ./configure

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I tried to install Reaver. The read me file gives a procedure and the first step is to use the following code in the corresponding location.

```
root@ubuntu:/media/New Volume/reaver-1.4/src# ./configure
```

This was the result

```
bash: ./configure: Permission denied
```

I tried changing the file permission using chmod. But after the command is executed it changes it's permission back to the default one.

Comment: You tried `chmod +x ./configure`, right?

Comment: Yes I tried it, but it shows the same.

Comment: Why don't you copy first the source files to your home directory?

Comment: its because you're working on your inserted volume directory i think. copy first to your home directory and `./configure` there.

Comment: @nickanor I do this but it won't help

Answer (score 7):

This happens because you are trying to install from other drives. Copy the content in the home directory then try installing using `./configure`. It will work. Also change the permission using `chmod a+x -R` command.

Answer (score 7):

I had this error because I was trying to run the command on a mounted partition that had the "noexec" flag on.

After remounting to remove this flag, everything worked fine. With this command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/MOUNTEDDISKNAME
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to you are downloaded and extracted source code with the Windows line ending. Try to use some distribution that containing Unix line endings.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the `configure` file already has execute permission, this happens when the `config.log` file has been created by another user or inaccessible (either you tried `./configure` with `sudo` or somebody else has run the `configure` script already). Removing the `config.log` file should solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes such things happen when you extracting files from gzipped tarball with improper applications or(and) from another user.

In that case "`tar -xf ...` " solves the problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer @grs444, but did you notice that the question was 7 years old?

Comment: does it really matter?

Comment: No, not at all, the person who asked never ticked an answer as the accepted answer. I just wasn't sure you'd noticed.

Comment: For the truth - i didn'd. I hope my words would help somebody .. someday)

Answer (score -4):

Just use `sh ./configure`. It will work.

Comment: sh ./configure will only partially work. You still need permission to compile programs and your solution does not address that.