# Can't change permissions on extracted files Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

I'm trying to install a program from the *.x86_64 file but it seems I don't have the right permissions to do it.

Even if I right-click and go in the "Permission" tab, when I try to change anything (Either any of the drop down menus or the "Execute" check box) it just change right back to the previous state (unchecked).

When I try to :

```
gksu nautilus
```

to change the permission under superuser, it just crash :

```
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed:
'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open
usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or
directory Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.

** ERROR:nautilus-properties-window.c:1837:schedule_owner_change_timeout:assertion failed: (NAUTILUS_IS_FILE (file))
```

Then I tryed to change permissions and ownership of the folder using different ways :

`sudo chmod -x *.x86_64`

or

```
chmod -R 777 (folder)
```

nothing changes.

When I use on the folder I get:

```
ls -l 
drwx------ 1 psyc0p4th psyc0p4th       4096 Jan 29 06:38   (folder)
```

When I try it inside the folder (where the files are), I get :

```
-rw------- 1 psyc0p4th psyc0p4th 83827576 Jan 29 06:37 sounds.dat
```

on every single files.

Those files come from a downloaded tar.gz. The tar also have the same problem.

I tried to decompress using different program (xarchiver, p7zip, the tar command line) and I have the same result.
The only thing different is that in xarchiver, the permissions are listed as "-rwxr-xr-x" but not after the decompression.

Other infos :

```
psyc0p4th@psyc0p4th-X550CA:/$ mount 
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4
(rw,errors=remount-ro) proc on /proc type proc
(rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) sysfs on /sys type sysfs
(rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw) none
on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw) none on
/sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw) none on /sys/kernel/security type
securityfs (rw) none on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755) devpts on /dev/pts type
devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620) tmpfs on /run type tmpfs
(rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755) none on /run/lock type tmpfs
(rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880) none on /run/shm type tmpfs
(rw,nosuid,nodev) none on /run/user type tmpfs
(rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755) none on
/sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw) /dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup
(rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd) gvfsd-fuse on
/run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse
(rw,nosuid,nodev,user=psyc0p4th) /dev/sr0 on /media/psyc0p4th/Perfect
Stranger type udf
(ro,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,umask=0077,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda6 on /media/psyc0p4th/DATA type fuseblk
(rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda7 on /media/psyc0p4th/Restore type fuseblk
(rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /media/psyc0p4th/Recovery type fuseblk
(rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)

psyc0p4th@psyc0p4th-X550CA:/$ arch 
x86_64
```

I also tried doing all of that logged in as root, no result.

I've been using Linux for about a month now, so i'm pretty new to all this, if you need any other informations just ask.
Thanks for everything.

Comment: Is this a .deb file? Are you running `dpkg -i <file name>.deb`?

Comment: No, the compressed files are .tar.gz (tarball?). The files inside are either a .i686 or .x86_64.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem. I moved the files from the Downloads directory to Home directory. I can now change all the permissions for all the files, and execute the .x86_64 file.

I found the idea there : 
[Permission Denied when using ./configure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288687/permission-denied-when-using-configure)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and navigate to directory where tar.gz at using `cd` for example: `cd /home/yourname/Downloads/` and do next:

if you need to install tar.gz or tar.bz2:

If it's tar.gz use

```
tar xvzf packagename.tar.gz
```

if it's a tar.bz2 use

```
tar xvjf packagename.tar.bz2
```

and then

```
./configure

 make

sudo make install
```

though I advise to use Chekinstall `sudo aptitude install checkinstall` it's even recommended. And instead of `make` and `sudo make install` use `sudo checkinstall` because it stores your manual installations to the system which can be easily removed then.

Comment: There is no install file and/or configure file. The aptitude install checkinstall fails, and the sudo checkinstall as well : 

        ========================= Installation results ===========================
    make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
    
    ****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.
    
    Cleaning up...OK
    
    Bye.

Comment: it's not a file! you need to run this in Terminal :-) wait a sec I'll re-edit the post

Comment: Ok, sorry, i get it. It still doesnt work : 

bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: read now the answer

Comment: also do consider installing `Checkinstall` it's just my advise you decide :-)

Comment: It is installed, still.. no results

Comment: this workout works 100% just make sure you follow every step correctly after you extracted file using `tar` and cannot compile for some reason go into the extracted folder and find `readme` or something like that `install.txt` e.g. file sometimes there are packages that depend on smth different.

Comment: `psyc0p4th@psyc0p4th-X550CA:/media/psyc0p4th/DATA/app$ ./configure`

`bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

`psyc0p4th@psyc0p4th-X550CA:/media/psyc0p4th/DATA/app$ make`
`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`
`psyc0p4th@psyc0p4th-X550CA:/media/psyc0p4th/DATA/app$ sudo make install`
`make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.`

Comment: you don't need to run `sudo make install` but `sudo checkinstall` are you doing that?

Comment: and again check extracted folder for `readme` or `install` cuz it might need build-essentials to build a package then you'll have to run `qmake`

Comment: Yep.
 > ========================= Installation results =========================== 
 > make: *** No rule to make target `install'. Stop. **** 
 > Installation failed. 
 > Aborting package creation. 
 > Cleaning up...
 > OK Bye.

There is no readme or install files.

(sorry for the text formating, it seems I can't do it right)

Comment: Then qmake it will be. I'll read on this. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome, so it works?

Comment: Not as of now, I have to understand how qmake works first

Comment: it depends if package needs it anyways if so you should run `qmake` and then `sudo checkinstall` that's it.

Comment: Thanks. But I still have the permission problem ;)

Comment: you run it with `sudo`? try `sudo su` then, but it should work with `sudo` anyways

Comment: just out of curiosity what file package is this?

Comment: Run what with sudo? The .x86_64 file?

Comment: I'm asking what is this file what do you need it for what does it do? p.s. run with `sudo` installation process not as a user

Comment: It's a game, and from what I gathered .x86_64 are the executable for games. It's not the game I actually care for, its the permission problem. Yes I ran everything with sudo.

Comment: I don't know what is that game package for but you can [download this](http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php/CPU-G?content=113796&PHPSESSID=d5059fc0f6c754ba6ae0865da95e0cf5) and compile it with `sudo tar xvzf packagename` after `sudo checkintall` to see for youself that it works. That's going to look like a chat, so good luck!

Comment: I know, I tryed to chat but I don't have enough reputation to do it. Thank you! I'm not sure how that application will help, but i'll download it and check. thanks a lot

Comment: that package will show you that you can compile it that everything works with compiling and the problem is in that compiling game package not permissions. :-)

Comment: sudo checkinstall doesn't work

Comment: it does work indeed! cuz I just compiled it yesterday using the same commands I've told you... if you can install a simple package with `sudo` but can't compile it and install a package at all you might be missing some dependencies or you got something messed in registry or you're doing something wrong. Type for example `sudo apt-cache show checkinstall` to see what package depends on and if you have this installed.

Comment: Depends: dpkg-dev, file, libc6 (>= 2.14). The 3 of them are up to date.

Ok let recapitulate. `sudo tar xvzf 113796-cpu-g-0.9.0.tar.gz` `cd cpu-g-0.9.0` `./configure` `sudo checkinstall`

I'm I doing it right

Comment: no! check the top answer of this conversation! you should navigate to file directory using `cd` then run `tar` and then `sudo checkinstall`

Comment: Yeah, thats what I did, I just used `cd` to get inside the unpacked folder so I can run `sudo checkinstall`. And still, I have the `****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.` message

Comment: are you doing this at your personal home machine from the same account as the root?

Comment: Yep, home machine, I only have 1 account

Comment: I have no clue what is going over there... did you try run those comands with `sudo su` ? it logins you as root

Comment: Yes, all have been done under root

Comment: the ultimate you can `auto-apt` for building packages it will automatically search for headers `sudo apt-get install auto-apt` then `sudo auto-apt update` then `sudo auto-apt updatedb && sudo auto-apt update-local` it may take some time, then instead of `./configure` you use `auto-apt run ./configure` that's ultimate solution otherwise you're doing something wrong.